How to load Nativewind configuration dynamically?
I'm working with React native v47.2 and nativewind v2, I want to create a white label App where I can load the tailwind config file dynamically.
Example:
tailwind.config.brandA.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
   extend: {
    colors: {
     primary: '#fff',
     secondary: '#000',
    },
 },
}

tailwind.config.brandB.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
   extend: {
    colors: {
     primary: '#000',
     secondary: '#fff',
    },
 },
}

tailwind.config.js
const path = require('path');
const brandConfigPath = process.env.TAILWIND_CONFIG || './src/config/tailwind/brands/tailwind.config.brandA.js';

const config = require(path.resolve(brandConfigPath));

module.exports = config;

App.js
<View className="bg-primary p-4 flex-1 justify-center items-center">
            <Text className="text-white font-sans">
                This text uses the primary color for the active brand.
            </Text>
        </View><View className="bg-primary p-4 flex-1 justify-center items-center">
            <Text className="text-white font-sans">
                This text uses the primary color for the active brand.
            </Text>
        </View>

So if I run  TAILWIND_CONFIG=.src/config/tailwind/brands/tailwind.config.brandA.js npx react-native start --reset-cache It works. But is this an optimal approach? What are your thoughts?
